# org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I have the following configuration in my spring bean.xml, when I run i get the ERROR: as mentioned below. I could not understand what the below configuration tag and use of it. where to specify the config.file

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location">
    <value>file:#{ systemProperties['config.file']}</value>
</property>
```

Error:
Exception in thread "main" `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you remembering to pass the value `-Dconfig.file=c:/blah/blah.config.props`

Comment: yes, in .bat file they are calling the class which has main.java. in .bat file, set CONFIG=%CURRPATH%/../config/fetchUnassignedSales.conf
set LOGFILE=%CURRPATH%/../logs/fetch-unassigned-sales.log

java -classpath "%APPCLASSPATH%" "-Dconfig.file=%CONFIG%" "-Dlog.file=%LOGFILE%" com.moodys.pfg.unassignedsales.FetchNewSalesProcessLauncher

Comment: I sugegst you try hard coding it to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: that error has gone. but when i load the bean file. it says, below :      Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'saleFetchProcess' is defined